# Revise qualification MTurk

Tags: mechanicalturk

I've loaded a qualification test into Sandbox on MTURK but I can't figure out how to remove or update it. When I revised the test, I get the following error:

```
The qualification type for name '(Test) General Knowledge Quiz' already exists.
```

I've tried `./updateQualification` and `./resetAccount.sh` but neither seem to work. I've also tried `./DisposeQualificationType.sh` but I can't get it to work.

When I use the following code (I've replaced the qualtypeid with my unique ID)

`./updateQualificationType.sh -qualtypeid RWFZTKZ55ZPZXN1C8TDZ -question sur
vey.question`

I get the following error messsage:

```
Error updating qualification type: Error executing operation: Error #1 for RequestId: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX - AWS.MissingParameters: Your request is missing required parameters. Required parameters include TestDuration. TestDuration is missing. (1424574121742 s)
com.amazonaws.mturk.service.exception.InternalServiceException: Error executing operation: Error #1 for RequestId: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX  AWS.MissingParameters: Your request is missing required parameters. Required parameters include TestDuration. TestDuration is missing.. (1424574121742 s)
```

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation for UpdateQualificationType](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_UpdateQualificationTypeOperation.html). You cannot change the name of a QualificationType. You could dispose it, though, and lose any associated worker qualifications; then create a new QualificationType with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add an option to specify the `.properties` file in the `./updateQualificationType.sh` code because AWS can't find the time delay in seconds that is specified in that file. Your code should look like:

```
./updateQualificationType.sh -qualtypeid RWFZTKZ55ZPZXN1C8TDZ -question qualification.question -properties qualification.properties
```